# Is there a way to specify an offset in Tailwind css?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to display some text and an image next to it in one row.
I am using Tailwind Css as much as possible and I would like to add and offset of 1/8 of the width so that there is some margin between the text and the image

```
<div class="grid section">
    <div class="w-full">
        <div class="w-5/8">
            <p> Whatever text ...</p>
        </div>
        <div class="w-2/8">
            <img src="whatever.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What would be the name of the offset class in Tailwind to add a left offset of w-1/8 to the img div wrapper, if there is one?

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve. This example makes the text (blue) take up 2/6 of the parent's space while the image div will take up the remaining 4/6: https://play.tailwindcss.com/pzd55OjDn1 
There is no /8 class in the default Tailwind config.

Answer (score 1):

Use scroll-margin. It allows you to control the scroll offset. Like so:

```
<div class="w-2/8 scroll-m-8">
```

More details on scroll offsets on the official Tailwind [documentation here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/scroll-margin).

Answer (score -2):

You almost answered your own question:

> ...  so that there is some margin between the text and the image

You need to add margin to the image. In this case you would add `mt-20` (or possibly a different size) to image's div, which means *margin top*. Other margin classes exist and they are well [documented](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin).

Live example [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/jqcoaDNSfy).